# Trouble using subqueries and/or with

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here's the deal I have one column to identify quarter and one to identify year. I need to group the sum of a column by another column, how do I join the with statements or use the subqueries properly? Having troubles?

Here is me trying with with, im not sure how to join these statements and have the column company name out front?

```
WITH Q219 (Comp,Q219) AS
(
SELECT [Company Name - As Is],SUM(NSB) FROM [insta].[dbo].[sample$]
WHERE Quarter = 'Q2' AND Year = 2019
          GROUP BY [Company Name - As Is]
),
 Q319 (Comp,Q319) AS
(
SELECT [Company Name - As Is],SUM(NSB) FROM [insta].[dbo].[sample$]
WHERE Quarter = 'Q2' AND Year = 2019
          GROUP BY [Company Name - As Is]
),
 Q318 (Comp,Q318) AS
(
SELECT [Company Name - As Is],SUM(NSB) FROM [insta].[dbo].[sample$]
WHERE Quarter = 'Q3' AND Year = 2018
          GROUP BY [Company Name - As Is]
)

 select Q318,Q219,Q319 from Q318,Q219,Q319
 go
```

Also tried with subqueries but can't get it to work

```
SELECT 

Q219 = 
(SELECT SUM(NSB) FROM [insta].[dbo].[sample$]
        WHERE Quarter = 'Q2' AND Year = 2019
          GROUP BY [Company Name - As Is]),
Q319 = ....


  FROM [insta].[dbo].[sample$]
```

Comment: For `Q319` you have `Quarter = 'Q2' AND Year = 2019`. Shouldn't it be `Quarter = 'Q3'`?

Comment: Yep that's why my numbers were off! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I got it, looks like my numbers are off though

```
 select  Q318.Comp,Q318,Q219,Q319 from Q318
 Join Q219
 ON Q318.Comp=Q219.Comp
 JOIN Q319
 ON Q219.Comp=Q319.Comp
 go
```